# Spell-Checker c++; checking whether the word is in the dictionary text

Tags: c++, string, iterator, unordered-set

I'm new to this place so I might not ask my questions clearly. But I really do need help. So my homework is to create a spell-checker in C++ which takes a text file and compares it with another dictionary text file. I have a specific snippet of code that I need solving. I created a help function **isValidWord** which takes in the dictionary which is of container unordered_set and a string. The function will return true if the string matches a word in the dictionary. I'll just show you what I have so far. My problem is the string doesn't match with everything in the library and just checks only some in the dictionary.

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>
bool isValidWord(std::unordered_set<std::string> dictionary, std::string& word) {
        std::unordered_set<std::string>::iterator it;
        for (it = dictionary.begin(); it != dictionary.end(); ++it) {
            if (word == *it) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Is the reason it doesn't match to do with the CASE of the letters?

Comment: Can you show an example input where the string doesn't match against everything?

Comment: @CodeGorilla the case problem is already taken care of

Comment: @SebastianStern the string will only check against 2 words in the dictionary, when the dictionary has 80k+ words

Comment: Pass the dictionary by reference as well please, you dont want to pass it by value `bool isValidWord(std::unordered_set<std::string>& dictionary...`

Comment: @Yang Where do you get this dictionary  from? Are you sure that you are loading all 80k+ words from it?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger to see what the values of your dictionary are and why it stops iterating?

Comment: @SamerTufail thanks for the insight

Comment: @VTT the dictionary is just a collection of standard words that people use. It was provided by my professor.

Comment: I finally got it right lol. It's because I didn't add the reference that caused the program to process to slowly.

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a built-in [`find` method in `unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) that you can utilize instead of reinventing the wheel. Also it is a good idea to pass `dictionary` by reference to avoid pointless copying.

Answer (score 1):

You may simplify your method with (I added missing `const` and reference too):

```
bool isValidWord(const std::unordered_set<std::string>& dictionary,
                 const std::string& word)
{
    return dictionary.count(word) != 0;
}
```

Your current implementation is correct but not performant:

- you pass your dictionary by copy (so you recreate it each time).
- You use linear search whereas container provide better complexity. (`std::unordered_set::find` or `std::unordered_set::count`).

Final note, if you want to retrieve all invalid words, you may look at `std::set_difference` (require to have words and dictionary sorted).

Comment: that's such an elegant snippet of code. Thank you so much